# Android Wear onPeerConnected not called with new Wear Intents

Tags: wear-os

I have been using the following intent-filter in my manifest and everything worked fine:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
```

This has been deprecated so I am trying to use:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CAPABILITY_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.CHANNEL_EVENT" />
<data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/mypath" />
```

I can receive messages fine but onPeerConnected never gets called now.

```
public class WearListenerService extends WearableListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node peer) {
        Log.d("Wear Service", "Peer Connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        Log.d("Wear Service", "Message Received");
    }

}
```

Everything works perfect if I switch back to using the old BIND_LISTENER instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`onPeerConnected` was deprecated at the same time as `BIND_LISTENER`, so when you stop using the latter, you need to stop using the former as well.

For comparable functionality, use the Cabability API: `CAPABILITY_CHANGED` in your manifest, and a `CapabilityListener` in your Java code. More details here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#SendMessage

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I sure find the Google documentation lacking, but maybe that is just me.